# Trying to loop through XML to extract values in PLSQL

Tags: xml, plsql

I am trying to loop through XML and extract the UUIDs. I have the following and it is looping through the correct number of times and printing a blank row each time. Why is it not extracting the text value of the UUID node?

```
   DECLARE
       X XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
         <StatusUp>
           <G_UUIDs>
               <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
               <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
               <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
               <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
           </G_UUIDs>
        </StatusUp>');
    BEGIN
       FOR r IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), 'StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID/text()') AS uuid

                   FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(X, '//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID'))) p)
       LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UUID' || r.uuid);
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to convert this to a sql statement and run it, like so:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
         <StatusUp>
           <G_UUIDs>
               <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
               <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
               <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
               <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
           </G_UUIDs>
        </StatusUp>') x FROM dual)
SELECT p.*,
       EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), 'StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID/text()') AS uuid
FROM   sample_data sd,
       TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(sd.x, '//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID'))) p;
```

it would be easy to spot the problem:

```
COLUMN_VALUE             UUID
------------------------ ----------
<UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
<UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
<UUID>3 test 3 </UUID> 
<UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
```

I.e. you're trying to extract the node `StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID` from xml that only contains the node `UUID`. Instead, if you correct the node you're querying for, you get the right result:

```
DECLARE
   X XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
     <StatusUp>
       <G_UUIDs>
           <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
           <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
           <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
           <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
       </G_UUIDs>
    </StatusUp>');
BEGIN
   FOR r IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), 'UUID/text()') AS uuid
               FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(X, '//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID'))) p)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UUID' || r.uuid);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

UUID1 test 1
UUID2 test 2
UUID3 test 3 
UUID4 test 4
```

However, EXTRACT and EXTRACTVALUE are deprecated - you should be using XMLTABLE instead:

```
DECLARE
   X XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
     <StatusUp>
       <G_UUIDs>
           <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
           <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
           <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
           <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
       </G_UUIDs>
    </StatusUp>');
BEGIN
   FOR r IN (SELECT *
             FROM   XMLTABLE('//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID'
                             PASSING x
                             COLUMNS uuid varchar2(10) PATH '.'))
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UUID' || r.uuid);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

UUID1 test 1
UUID2 test 2
UUID3 test 3 
UUID4 test 4
```

---

Equivalent query that you should try running:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
         <StatusUp>
           <G_UUIDs>
               <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
               <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
               <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
               <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
           </G_UUIDs>
        </StatusUp>') x FROM dual)
SELECT *
FROM   sample_data sd,
       XMLTABLE('//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID'
                PASSING sd.x
                COLUMNS uuid varchar2(10) PATH '.');
```

Comment: thanks I had just figured out the issue with the extractvalue node being wrong and was about to answer my own question. I was unaware of XMLTABLE and will look at that.

Comment: I get an error when i run the xmltable suggestion, specifically: Error at line 1
ORA-19114: error during parsing the XQuery expression: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
ORA-06512: at line 12

Comment: Are you getting that error with the code I gave you? Because that worked without error for me. If so, what version of Oracle are you running it on?

Comment: @bonesit I am on Oracle 10g and yes it was your exact code that I was trying to run.

Comment: Hmm. It definitely runs ok on 11.2.0.4. There's a query I'd like you to try, which is the equivalent of the stored proc which I've added to my question - when you run it, do you still get an error?

Comment: yes I still get an error: Error at line 1
ORA-19114: error during parsing the XQuery expression: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Seems like maybe your version of the db is hitting a bug, then. What is the exact version? You can obtain that by running `select version from v$instance;`

Comment: specific version is 10.2.0.2.0

Comment: It's probably a bug in that version of Oracle, then. You'll have to stick to the "old" way of doing things, then

Answer (score 1):

You've already extracted UUID from XML in FROM statement, and in select, figuratively speaking, you now only have four rows

```
<UUID> n test n </UUID>
```

So the correct way to extract that data be:

```
DECLARE
  X XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE(
    '<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <StatusUp>
      <G_UUIDs>
        <UUID>1 test 1</UUID>
        <UUID>2 test 2</UUID>
        <UUID>3 test 3 </UUID>
        <UUID>4 test 4 </UUID>
      </G_UUIDs>
    </StatusUp>');
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT
              EXTRACTVALUE(
                VALUE(p),
                --'StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID/text()') AS uuid
                '/UUID/text()') AS uuid
            FROM
              TABLE(
                XMLSEQUENCE(
                  EXTRACT(
                    X,
                    '//StatusUp/G_UUIDs/UUID')
                )
              ) p
           )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.uuid);
  END LOOP;
END;
```