# Extracting node-value using XMLTable with p499: prefix for nodes gives error message

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, oracle12c

Hi I have the following XML message

```
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
       <p66:retrieveOrderStatusResponse 
       xmlns:p66="http://v1_2.ostat.services.view.jdpoint.parts.deere.com">
             <p66:retrieveOrderStatusReturn xmlns:p499="http://beans.v1_2.ostat.services.view.jdpoint.parts.deere.com">
                <p499:version>1.2</p499:version>
                <p499:accountNumber></p499:accountNumber>
                <p499:currency></p499:currency>
                <p499:dateOrdered>09Sep2011 07:25:17</p499:dateOrdered>
                <p499:dealerRef>P1092293</p499:dealerRef>
                <p499:destination xsi:nil="true"/>
                <p499:discountTotal>0,00</p499:discountTotal>
                <p499:estimatedOrderValue>162,71</p499:estimatedOrderValue>
                <p499:exceptionReport xsi:nil="true"/>
                <p499:extendedPriceTotal>162,71</p499:extendedPriceTotal>
                <p499:lastChanged>SYSTEM</p499:lastChanged>
                <p499:lineOfCredit xsi:nil="true"/>
                <p499:merchandiseTotal></p499:merchandiseTotal>
                <p499:orderNumber></p499:orderNumber>
                <p499:orderStatus>RLSED</p499:orderStatus>
                <p499:orderType>ORD_EMER</p499:orderType>
                <p499:partialShip>1 - PRTSHP_CD1</p499:partialShip>
                <p499:orderNotes/>
                <p499:shipAddress>
                   <p499:shipAddressName></p499:shipAddressName>
                   <p499:shipAddressLine1></p499:shipAddressLine1>
                   <p499:shipAddressLine2/>
                   <p499:shipAddressCity></p499:shipAddressCity>
                   <p499:shipAddressStateProvince/>
                   <p499:shipPostalCode></p499:shipPostalCode>
                   <p499:shipAddressCountry></p499:shipAddressCountry>
                   <p499:shipAddressPhone/>
                </p499:shipAddress>
                <p499:billingAddress>
                   <p499:billAddressName></p499:billAddressName>
                   <p499:billAddressLine1></p499:billAddressLine1>
                   <p499:billAddressLine2></p499:billAddressLine2>
                   <p499:billAddressCity></p499:billAddressCity>
                   <p499:billAddressStateProvince/>
                   <p499:billPostalCode></p499:billPostalCode>
                   <p499:billAddressCountry></p499:billAddressCountry>
                   <p499:billAddressPhone/>
                </p499:billingAddress>
                <p499:poolCode>UF</p499:poolCode>
                <p499:programNumber/>
                <p499:programTerm/>
                <p499:returnCode>1</p499:returnCode>
                <p499:submittedBy>PMLINK</p499:submittedBy>
                <p499:surchargeTotal>0,00</p499:surchargeTotal>
                <p499:vin/>
                <p499:orderLines>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>ProcessedOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0001</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber>01</p499:splitLineNumber>
                      <p499:quantity>2</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F025234</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>O-Ring</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice></p499:extendedPrice>
                      <p499:shipDate>14Sep2011</p499:shipDate>
                      <p499:depot></p499:depot>
                      <p499:packlistNumber></p499:packlistNumber>
                      <p499:status>SHIPPED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>ProcessedOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0002</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber>01</p499:splitLineNumber>
                      <p499:quantity>2</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F003308</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>O-Ring</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice></p499:extendedPrice>
                      <p499:shipDate>09Sep2011</p499:shipDate>
                      <p499:depot></p499:depot>
                      <p499:packlistNumber></p499:packlistNumber>
                      <p499:status>SHIPPED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>ProcessedOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0003</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber>01</p499:splitLineNumber>
                      <p499:quantity>1</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F050813</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>Seal</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice></p499:extendedPrice>
                      <p499:shipDate>09Sep2011</p499:shipDate>
                      <p499:depot></p499:depot>
                      <p499:packlistNumber></p499:packlistNumber>
                      <p499:status>SHIPPED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>ProcessedOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0004</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber>01</p499:splitLineNumber>
                      <p499:quantity>1</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F009469</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>Seal</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice>30,00</p499:extendedPrice>
                      <p499:shipDate>09Sep2011</p499:shipDate>
                      <p499:depot>Stockholm</p499:depot>
                      <p499:packlistNumber></p499:packlistNumber>
                      <p499:status>SHIPPED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>EnteredOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0005</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber/>
                      <p499:quantity>1</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F009465</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>Sealing Ring</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice/>
                      <p499:shipDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:depot/>
                      <p499:packlistNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:status>ORDERED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                   <p499:orderLine>
                      <p499:type>ProcessedOrderLine</p499:type>
                      <p499:lineNumber>0005</p499:lineNumber>
                      <p499:splitLineNumber>01</p499:splitLineNumber>
                      <p499:quantity>2</p499:quantity>
                      <p499:partNumber>F009465</p499:partNumber>
                      <p499:binLocation></p499:binLocation>
                      <p499:partDescription>Sealing Ring</p499:partDescription>
                      <p499:partName xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:extendedPrice></p499:extendedPrice>
                      <p499:shipDate>0</p499:shipDate>
                      <p499:depot>S</p499:depot>
                      <p499:packlistNumber>4200D252100185</p499:packlistNumber>
                      <p499:status>SHIPPED</p499:status>
                      <p499:lineNotes/>
                      <p499:investigations/>
                      <p499:specialPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:specialPriceNote xsi:nil="true"/>
                      <p499:drivenPrice xsi:nil="true"/>
                   </p499:orderLine>
                </p499:orderLines>
                <p499:shipments>
                   <p499:shipment>
                      <p499:shipUnit></p499:shipUnit>
                      <p499:lineCount>5</p499:lineCount>
                      <p499:viaUnit>DIRECT</p499:viaUnit>
                      <p499:carrierService>203 SE - DANX      DANX</p499:carrierService>
                      <p499:requestedShipDate>09Sep2011</p499:requestedShipDate>
                      <p499:estWeight>0,057</p499:estWeight>
                      <p499:breakPointCarrier/>
                      <p499:breakPointCity/>
                  <p499:breakPointState/>
                  <p499:carrierPaymentRespInd></p499:carrierPaymentRespInd>
                  <p499:freightChargesNeededInd></p499:freightChargesNeededInd>
               </p499:shipment>
            </p499:shipments>
            <p499:investigations/>
         </p66:retrieveOrderStatusReturn>
      </p66:retrieveOrderStatusResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I want to extract the p499:partNumber values (in the p499:orderLines/p499:orderLine path.

I have the xml message stored in XMLType variable named l_resp_xml_ := XMLType.createXML(soap_respond_);

I have tried to follow this code on this thread: [Trying to loop through XML to extract values in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614923/trying-to-loop-through-xml-to-extract-values-in-plsql)

Which gave me this:

FOR x in (

```
       SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE('//p66:retrieveOrderStatusResponse/p66:retrieveOrderStatusReturn/p499:orderLines/p499:orderLine/partNumber'


       PASSING l_resp_xml_
       COLUMNS partNumber varchar2(200) PATH '.'))
```

Then I do a dmbs_output.put_line(x.partNumber);
but that comes out blank and I get an error message saying:
ORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix 'p66' local-name 'p66:retrieveOrderStatusResponse'

Can anyone help me what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `XMLNAMESPACES` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soapenv",
                                        'http://v1_2.ostat.services.view.jdpoint.parts.deere.com' as "p66",
                                        'http://beans.v1_2.ostat.services.view.jdpoint.parts.deere.com' as "p499"
                                      ),'/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/p66:retrieveOrderStatusResponse/p66:retrieveOrderStatusReturn/p499:orderLines/p499:orderLine/p499:partNumber'


       PASSING l_resp_xml_
       COLUMNS partNumber varchar2(200) PATH '.')
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm